# What is the difference between "run after someone/something" and "run for someone/something"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Tell me please the difference between the following sentences.

> I ran **after** the bus as fast as I could.
>
> I ran **for** the bus as fast as I could.

To me it feels as though the first sentence means that the runner was chasing the bus with no intention to get on it, whereas the second one seems to mean that the runner wanted get on board. I am not sure though if my thinking is correct. If it is, then what about the following pair of sentences?

> The police officer ran **after** the suspect.
>
> The police officer ran **for** the suspect.

I cannot think of any difference between these two. Is there any?

Comment: As you say, to _run after_ something is to chase it. We would normally speak of _running for_ a bus. No-one would use _run for_ when speaking of a person being pursued. You might _run for_ assistance, or for an object that was needed, where the sense is _run to fetch_.